# Load .wav files into tensorflow.Data.Dataset

Tags: tensorflow, wav, tensorflow-datasets

I have few hundred wav files on which I am building an auto encoder. But I cannot load all the .wav files into the notebook since it crashes quickly. How do I load the data into tensorflow.data.dataset?

Answer (score 0):

To load an audio file, you will use `tf.audio.decode_wav`, which returns the WAV-encoded audio as a Tensor and the sample rate. More information about the library can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/audio/decode_wav).

Sample code below

```
def decode_audio(audio_binary):
  audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(audio_binary)
  return tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)
```

Reading audio files and their labels is explained [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio#reading_audio_files_and_their_labels).